# How to get pvob name by a given element name?

Tags: clearcase

I'm doing some scripting with ClearCase and I have to provide a pvob name.
I'm in a context of a view (dynamic or snapshot) and I have an element name (e.g. `<path>\filename.cpp`) or specific element and file version (`<path>\filename.cpp@@\main\versioname\2`)

How do I get its pvob?
Seems like I have to figure out the vob name and then find its linkage to a pvob?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct link between a vob element and a PVob (which contains reference to UCM objects)

What you can do is, within the current path of your element:

```
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

That will give you the name of the Stream of the view, which is attached to a PVob.
However, your element could be part of a component from another pvob.

Another option is to list all the components for all pvobs, with their root directory, and check the one with a root directory similar to the path of your element.

Note: one other link is in the activity: a `cleartool descr -l yourElement` would display the activity (and its pvob).
But again, that pvob can be different of the component one from which your element is part of.

---

A bit more direct link: do a dump of your element

```
cleartool dump -l /path/to/your/element

[...]
derived objects:
hyperlinks to object:
arrow=1249731306
  type=27209
  hlink vob=90b77fed.efb24bb6.8312.8e:09:7f:84:65:a1
  hlink obj=64856a02.8d9d4624.abae.09:94:b0:e7:9c:2e
  from vob=90b77fed.efb24bb6.8312.8e:09:7f:84:65:a1    <=====
  from obj=20b6c0e8.270e4354.91f5.02:5c:6f:ed:41:54
  to vob=60efb222.0e034a34.aa4b.80:65:c3:9c:d4:ca      <=====
  to obj=eb7ec24a.510e4e03.8403.0b:e8:dd:3d:5c:db
```

Your element is linked to two vobs:

- The actual Vob (which contains files)
- The PVob (which is an 'ucmvob', ie a pvob)

You can list all your vobs, asking for their oid:

```
 ct descr -fmt "%On %[plevels]p" vob:\avob
```

You can check if its oid matches one of the hyperlinks of your element.

Note: I use  `%[plevels]p` because it is only valid on a pvob!